# How to Close Orthographic Scene Collection

Tags: scene, orthographic

How to Close Orthographic Scene Collection. It split into 4 windows and I can only use the User Scene window. How do you close it?

Answer (score 2):

Blender calls it  **Quad View** and it can be toggled with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, or (Header) > View Menu > Area > Toggle Quad View